# WPF bind image via WCF to TileLayoutControl from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, image, wcf, xaml, binding

My system is working like this.I have a WCF service,which is giving me ImageUrl and I am downloading this Image to my project directory and save it to my file system. Then I want to show this Image in Devexpress TileLayoutControl dynamically. But not showing anything on UI.Also I am not getting error. I tried to give ımage source like this ../MenuPhotos/imagename and like this /TileExample;component/MenuPhotos/imagename

My codes are like this;

XAML;

```
<dxlc:TileLayoutControl Name="TileList" AllowItemMoving="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ShowLayerSeparators="True" Padding="40,60,40,10" AllowLayerSizing="True" >

    <dxlc:TileLayoutControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="dxlc:Tile">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
            <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundColor}" />-->
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Size" Value="{Binding SizeType}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="/TileExample;component/MenuPhotos/restaurant1.jpg" />
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                            <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding IconImageUrl}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}" />
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BackgroundImageUrl}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="12" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="dxlc:TileLayoutControl.IsFlowBreak" Value="{Binding IsFlowBreak}" />
            <Setter Property="dxlc:TileLayoutControl.GroupHeader" Value="Menü" />
            <Setter Property="dxwuin:Navigation.NavigateTo" Value="{Binding PageName}" />
            <Setter Property="dxwuin:Navigation.NavigationParameter" Value="1" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="dxlc:TileGroupHeader">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </Style>

    </dxlc:TileLayoutControl.Resources>
</dxlc:TileLayoutControl>
```

And my viewmodel like this;

```
IEnumerable<ImageItemsModel> items;
public GroupedItemsViewModel()
{
}
public IEnumerable<ImageItemsModel> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    private set { SetProperty<IEnumerable<ImageItemsModel>>(ref items, value, "Items"); }
}
public void LoadState(object navigationParameter)
{
    MyServiceclient = new MyServiceclient();
    var items = client.GetAllItems(null);
    string remoteUri = "http://example.com/";
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (item.BackgroundImageUrl == null)
        {
            item.BackgroundImageUrl = "/TileExample;component/Assets/Images/user.jpg";
        }
        else
        {

            string remotefilepath = item.BackgroundImageUrl.Replace("../", "").Replace("//", "/");
            string remotefilename = remotefilepath.Replace("img/integration/Dashboard/bg/", "");
            string myStringWebResource = null;
            using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
            {
                string path = @"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TileExample\TileExample\MenuPhotos\";
                string checkpath = @"C:\Users\USER\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TileExample\TileExample\MenuPhotos\" + remotefilename;
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }
                if (!File.Exists(checkpath))
                {
                    myStringWebResource = remoteUri + remotefilepath;
                    try
                    {
                        string downloadintopath = Path.Combine(path, remotefilename);
                        myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, downloadintopath);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }

            item.BackgroundImageUrl = item.BackgroundImageUrl.Replace("../../img/integration/Dashboard/bg", "../MemberPhotos");
        }

    }

    Items = items;
}
#region INavigationAware Members
public void NavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
}
public void NavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    LoadState(e.Parameter);
}
public void NavigatingFrom(NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
}
#endregion
```

In UI I couldnt saw nothing about my images.If I will include images as a source to visual studio its working.But I will fill to image as a service. So I cannot use this workaround.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi recently I learn this solution:

In .NET 4.5 dynamic image path should be like this.

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/TileExample;component/MenuPhotos/restaurant1.jpg"></Image>
```

This solution working for me.